# Post an aac link in Facebook via FB Connect on iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

In my application I am able to post a link in my Facebook wall.
I am wondering if it's possible to post a link to an aac file and gets it playing on my wall.

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

As you might know, to post anything, you need to define a JSON string containing the stream publish contents.

As you need a link to the audio file, you need to provide it as part of the action_links parameter.
Take a look at the Facebook doc for more info (look for action_links):
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish

If what you need to do is to include the media directly:
Take a look at this (look at "Including Media in the Attachment"):
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments

This is how Im posting links, to anything (some code snippets I haven't tested):

```
//1. Create an array containing the action links. Each action link is a dictionary.

NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                                    @"link to google",@"text",
                                    @"http://www.google.com/",@"href", nil],
                                nil
                             ];

//2. convert the dictionary to a JSON string
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[[SBJSON alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *actionLinksAsJSON = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];

//3. Pass it as a parameter on the parameters dictionary
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setObject: theAPIKey forKey:@"api_key"];
[params setObject: theMessage forKey:@"user_message_prompt"];
[params setObject: actionLinksAsJSON forKey:@"action_links"];
[params setObject: attachmentAsJSON forKey:@"attachment"];
[params setObject: targetId forKey:@"target_id"];

NSLog(@"Parameters in stream.publish are: \n%@", params);
[self.facebook dialog: @"stream.publish"
            andParams: params
          andDelegate: self];
```

I hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I already did  that. I checked FB doc and saw music tag, which gives me an error "music type not supported". I found that the mp3 type is working but FB does not play my aac file...